# Parse PHP SDK unable to create query after installing with Composer

Tags: php, parse-platform, composer-php

I am trying to use the Parse PHP SDK to access some data from my parse server's database. I am adding the SDK to my project via Composer.

I installed Composer globally using their [documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#globally). Following [Parse's documentation](https://docs.parseplatform.org/php/guide/#install-with-composer), I added Parse to my `composer.json` file.
I was able to install the Parse SDK with no problem, but when I actually try to start querying objects with the SDK, I immediately receive errors.

I am getting the `Server connected - everything looks good!` message, but it is followed by a ParseException that just says Bad Request. Is there anything else required in order to create a query?

Here is my php:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Parse\ParseObject;
use Parse\ParseQuery;
use Parse\ParseACL;
use Parse\ParsePush;
use Parse\ParseUser;
use Parse\ParseInstallation;
use Parse\ParseException;
use Parse\ParseAnalytics;
use Parse\ParseFile;
use Parse\ParseCloud;
use Parse\ParseClient;
use Parse\ParsePushStatus;
use Parse\ParseServerInfo;
use Parse\ParseLogs;
use Parse\ParseAudience;


// Parse API Keys
$app_id = 'myAppIdGoesHere';
$master_key = 'myMasterKeyGoesHere';

// Initialize the ParseClient using Parse API keys:
ParseClient::initialize($app_id, null, $master_key);

//Set server url
ParseClient::setServerURL('https://my-server-url.com','parse');

//Verify server url and mount path are correct
$health = ParseClient::getServerHealth();
if($health['status'] === 200) {
    print('Server connected - everything looks good!');
}

function getStores() {
  $query = new ParseQuery("Stores");

  try {
    // The object was retrieved successfully.
    $results = $query->find();

    echo "Successfully retrieved " . count($results) . " stores.";

  } catch (ParseException $error) {
    // The object was not retrieved successfully.
    print $error;
  }
}

getStores();
```

Comment: Can you try to setup CA as shown [here](https://github.com/parse-community/parse-php-sdk#alternate-ca-file).

Comment: I downloaded the cert and put it in a certs/ folder as directed. I then added the `ParseClient::setCAFile(__DIR__ . '/certs/cacert.pem');` line below my server health check. It is still returning a bad request. When I do some digging, my request appears to be returning HTML and not JSON. Any thoughts?

Comment: How did you add your data to Parse Server?

Comment: What data are you referring to? If you're referring to table data, then mostly via POST requests over Parse's API or in some rare cases, manually adding via the web dashboard.

Comment: The data you're trying to fetch from Parse Server database. Can you put your code inside `try { ... } catch (ParseException $e) { ... }` block?

Comment: I already had at the time of posting my original question.